# What happened to French crew?

Tags: lost

After everyone but Danielle go under the temple, Danielle calls them "infected" and her husband even tries to shoot her when she puts her weapon down.

One could argue that Man in Black spoke to them and convinced to his cause, but this will not exactly make sense with them trying to kill some of their own instead of taking her with them.

So what happened to them that Danielle husband tried to kill her?

Answer (score 1):

It's later revealed that the Smoke Monster was responsible for causing the disease that caused everyone to turn on each other, and forcing Danielle's hand. The sickness is the disease that even the Others were doing the experiments on people for. Trying to discover 1) why infertility was occurring, and 2) people were just turning randomly into an "evil" version of themselves after just seconds earlier being just fine.

There was no known cure for the disease, but Sayid and Claire both rebel against the "evil" infection within them, allowing them to become their normal selves.

source: https://lostpedia.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sickness

Comment: It seems like infertility has nothing to do with the "sickness" - Man in Black was around long before Dharma even arrived and Dharma women had children, Ethan, for example, was conceived, carried out and born on the Island. Looks like infertility comes after the Swan incident, not prior to it and certainly doesn't look like it has any connections to Smoke Monster and "sickness"